# XSS（クロスサイトスクリプティング）の対応でhtmlspecialcharsを使ったら異なる現象が発生

Tags: php, html, xss

現在XSS（クロスサイトスクリプティング）のテストを行っていて、
PHPの対象箇所をhtmlspecialcharsの関数を用いて対応しています。

テスト用の値としてはalert(document.cookie)のスクリプトコード
をURLパラメータにセットしてみて、Cookie情報がポップアップされないように
修正を行っています。

しかしながら、あるHTMLファイル内にPHPで記述されたコードがあるのですが、
htmlspecialchars関数を使ったら、添付画面のように、
表示されてしまいます。
ポップアップすることは直ったようですが、画面にこのような文字列が表示
されるようになってしまいました。

何か思い当たる原因はないでしょうか？

試してみるべきことがあったら教えてください。

どうぞよろしくお願い致します。

[image: 不具合の画面]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`htmlspecialchars`か類似のエスケープ関数を2回実行しています。

元データ`'`→1回目のエスケープ`&quot;`→2回目のエスケープ`&amp;quot;`→(ブラウザ上での表示)`&quot;`

エスケープの原則は「値を利用するタイミングで行う」です。どこでエスケープをやっているか分からない状況になるとこのように二重エスケープになったりエスケープ漏れが生じます。

Comment: 横やりすみません。2回目は「&amp;quot;」ではないでしょうか？

Comment: [関連質問: 脆弱性対策におけるhtmlspecialchars()の使用箇所について](http://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/2408/%E8%84%86%E5%BC%B1%E6%80%A7%E5%AF%BE%E7%AD%96%E3%81%AB%E3%81%8A%E3%81%91%E3%82%8Bhtmlspecialchars%E3%81%AE%E4%BD%BF%E7%94%A8%E7%AE%87%E6%89%80%E3%81%AB%E3%81%A4%E3%81%84%E3%81%A6/2420#2420)

Comment: suzukis様、回答のお礼が遅れて申し訳ありません。業務でバタバタしていたもので・・・
ご回答いただいた内容で納得しました！ご指摘内容の通りでした。
なお、二重エスケープをすると今回私が質問した内容のようになりますが、これ以外に何か問題がありますでしょうか？

Comment: @Web_beginner ちょっとおたずねの意味がわからないのですが、シングルクオーテーションマークを表示すべきところが&quot;と表示されてしまうのはアプリケーションが必要な機能を満たしていない、という問題以外に、ということでしょうか。

Answer (score 2):

```
&quot;&gt;&lt;script&gt;alert(document.cookie)&lt;/script&gt;
```

は

```
"><script>alert(document.cookie)</script>
```

がhtmlspecialcharsで変換された結果です。  
テスト用に渡した値がそのまま（変換されて）表示されているのではないかと思いますが、
「">」から始まっているので、どこかで「<」「>」の数があっていないとかはあるかもしれません。

参考：「HTMLでよく使用される特殊文字」に記号と変換後の文字列の表があります。
http://www.iarumas.jp/pc/learning/html/special_character.html